# Python - Wildcard character generating vowels

Tags: python, string, recursion, replace

Folks,

Teaching myself python through open course ware and I have hit a wall on an assignment.

Basically, the user types in a word with an * in place for a vowel.
Example: 'd*g' for dig, dog, or dug.

The program I wrote will replace * to a value from object: vowels='aeiou' and then look through a list of words and see if there is a match. Example: d*g -> *dag: no match, deg: no match, dig: match; end search.

```
for char_vow in VOWELS:
  wildcard_word=word.replace('*',char_vow)
  print(wildcard_word)
  if wildcard_word in word_list:
      word=wildcard_word
      break
```

This worked perfectly when there was one '*', but my program can't handle two or more. For instance if the user put in d**th for death, the code would only check
daath, deeth, diith, dooth, duuth and then give back a false.

So then I thought recursion might be the answer and wrote out:

```
def wildcard_replacement(word):
    wildcard_word=""
    if word.find('*')==-1:
        return word
    else:
        for char_vow in VOWELS:
              wildcard_word=word.replace('*',char_vow,1)
              print(wildcard_word)
              if wildcard_word in word_list:
                  word=wildcard_word
                  break
              elif wildcard_word.find('*')!=-1:
                  return wildcard_replacement(wildcard_word)
        return wildcard_replacement(wildcard_word)

    print(wildcard_replacement(word))
```

This program searched for: daath, daeth, daith, daoth, dauth then stopped. Which in hindsight makes sense. There is no longer an *. But I want the first vowel to now flip over from an a to and e and then continue the replacement loop for the second wildcard. I am stuck...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you do a `return` in the `elif` branch (under you `for`).
So basically, you never iterate through all vowels at your upper level since once you've stopped a `*` and replaced it there are not more...

Suggestions (since, it appears you actually don't want a "*code*" reply):

1. Check whether the word belongs your dictionary (`word_list`) in the limit case (i.e. when there are not `*`);
2. Always send temporary result (after you've replaced one of the `*`) to the function;
3. If you want to `break` at the first encountered valid word, I'd check the result of called `wildcard_replacement` instead of something different (you actually do a verification on `wildcard_word` instead of returned value);

Comment: That helped a bunch! All set now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function is a good idea

```
def expand_vowels(word):
```

if we have no wild characters in `word`, we yield the unchanged word and use the `return` statement to signal that the recursion is over

```
    if '*' not in word: yield word ; return
```

if we are here there is at least one `'*'` in `word`

```
    for new_word in (word.replace('*', vw, 1) for v in 'aeiou'):
        for new2_word in expand_vowels(new_word): yield new2_word
```

It's easy to put all this together, with some simple tests too

```
$ cat vow.py
def expand_vowels(word):
    if '*' not in word: yield word ; return
    for new_word in (word.replace('*', v, 1) for v in 'aeiou'):
        for new2_word in expand_vowels(new_word): yield new2_word

for w in ('a', 'a*', 'a**'):
    print(list(expand_vowels(w)))

good = ['aei', 'bwe']

for wild in ('a**', 'b**'):
    for word in expand_vowels(wild):
        if word in good:
            print(word, 'is in the good words')
            break
    else:
        print(wild, 'doesn\'t generate a good word')
```

```
$ python vow.py
['a']
['aa', 'ae', 'ai', 'ao', 'au']
['aaa', 'aae', 'aai', 'aao', 'aau', 'aea', 'aee', 'aei', 'aeo', 'aeu', 'aia', 'aie', 'aii', 'aio', 'aiu', 'aoa', 'aoe', 'aoi', 'aoo', 'aou', 'aua', 'aue', 'aui', 'auo', 'auu']
aei is in the good words
b** doesn't generate a good word
$
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do here, is using *itertools product* you could specifiy the combinations of vowels needed in the example of `death` it would be `2` then we could set `repeat = 2` and get all 2 letter combinations of vowels, then we could use `str.replace` to replace the `'**'` with the vowel combinations until we get a match that is in `wordbank`

```
from itertools import product

vowels = 'aeiou'
wordbank = ['death']
word = 'd**th'
x = word.count('*')

l = [''.join(i) for i in [*product(vowels, repeat = x)]]
print(l)

for i in l:
    guess = word.replace('**', i)
    if guess in wordbank:
        print(guess)
        break
```

> ```
>  death
> ```